# Tags Input disappearing after reloading page

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Using tag input and thought it was working correctly. However when I reload the page, it no longer is there. I'm wondering what might be the case since everything else on my page, textboxes, checkbox, etc. are all working correctly and remain after reloading.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ipRestrictions" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label
                  control-label no-padding-right">IP Restrictions</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                              <tags-input use-strings="true" id="ipRestrictions"
                                       ng-model="targetEntity.ipRestrictions"
                                       placeholder="Add new host or IP">                                                            
                               </tags-input>
                         </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: create a demo example on plunkr.com or provide some more code. We cant conclude anything from this much code

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Perhaps, if you share what is that you want to achieve, someone may be able to suggest a way of realizing it that would be simpler. Besides, you stated "__...when I reload the page...__" and you are not explaining how the model is being retained/refreshed.